# Visibility of 2 user component in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, visibility

In my application got one sidebar, which is holding this two component :

```
        <Grid x:Name="AF" Visibility="Visibility">
            <betata:AForm Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="AR" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <betata:AReg Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
```

in the AForm got hyperlink button with this method :

```
    private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        betata.Views.Sidebar.Sidebar sd = new Sidebar();
        sd.showAR(this);
    }
```

back to my sidebar code got another method called showAR with these function :

```
    public void showAR(AForm aForm)
    { 
        this.AR.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        aForm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

but i not sure why the aForm will collapsed but AR could not become visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visibility of User Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983939/visibility-of-user-control)

Comment: because previously it could not solve and finally i found the solution at the end. but i didn't delete because i want to keep reference from @Aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question had been answer in this post. [Visibility of User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983939/make-visible-of-uc-c-in-uc-a-from-uc-b) can be solve via tunnelling and bubbling. which are new routing events function of silverlight

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor this a bit, to make it more simple (which might help to solve your problem).

```
<Grid>
  <betat:AForm x:Name="aForm" Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" />
  <betata:AReg x:Name="aReg" Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>

 public void showAR() // this is in the code behind (xaml.cs) of the Sidebar UserControl
 { 
      this.aReg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      this.aForm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
 }
```

or you don't even need the ShowAR() and could just set the visibility in the button click, unless you're reusing the function in other places.Example:

```
 private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      betata.Views.Sidebar.Sidebar sd = new Sidebar();
      sd.aReg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      sd.aForm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
 }
```

Comment: i tried @.@ it's not working... i mean when i clicking the hyperlink button got no respond

Comment: It seems like the click event isn't wired up... does your button look something like: <HyperlinkButton click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />?

Comment: it got that :: <HyperlinkButton Content="click me" Height="16" Margin="0,100,21,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="64" FontSize="10.667" ToolTipService.ToolTip="FOR OFFICIAL ADMIN ONLY" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />

Comment: and actually the code in question can make itself disappear but don't know why could not make the AReg form come back

Comment: @SLim if changing the visibility isn't showing/hiding it, there might be something else that is causing problems. You said that the button doesn't respond, have you put a break point in to observe it? Is there an element on top of the bottom (either z-index or placing an element further down in the XAML and having it on top of the other one could do this). Maybe you need to add RowDefinition to your overall grid?

Comment: i did put something like this txtAdminID.Text += 1; to test out the button, it's working fine. in the element sorting, i confirmed it's the highest layer while i placed on bottom of all other element. you mean of row definition is meaning of ??

Comment: <Grid><RowDefinition Height="Auto" /><RowDefinition Height="*" /></Grid>, but it seems like you've ruled out that as a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4644/discussion-between-slim-and-aligned)