# Visibility of User Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visibility

In my application got one sidebar, which is holding this two component :

```xml
        <Grid x:Name="AF" Visibility="Visibility">
            <betata:AForm Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="AN" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <betata:ANav Height="508" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
```

in the AForm got hyperlink button with this method :

```
    private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Sidebar sb = new Sidebar();
        sb.AN.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

but i not sure why the aForm will collapsed but AN could not become visible. or is there any other solution to implement ::

this line in main page to call up UC_A ::

```xml
<DWDS_LULCS_Views_Sidebar:Sidebar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="264"/>
```

- Main page
  holding
- User Control A (Sidebar)
  holding
- User Control B (admin login form)
  and
- User Control C (admin navigation menu)

UC_B default is visible, and click the button in UC_B to call UC_A's UC_C change the visibility to visible ?

Comment: this whole thing is very confusing... first, Visibility="Visibility" is wrong, also, why you are doing this? Sidebar sb = new Sidebar();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this problem is being solve... i do in this way, make something in global variable for verification whether which to make visible and collapse, then give one event handler to sidebar (layout_updated). when i modify the visibility of UC_B, UC_A will being affected and the trigger will be call. lastly, the UC_A's layout_updated event will change the visibility of UC_C become visible.

Answer (score 1):

> i do in this way, make something in global variable for verification whether which to make visible and collapse,

Another approach is to use an mvvm approach

```
<Border Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
```

In your resources you will need to add

```
<local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" OnTrue="Visible" OnFalse="Collapsed" />
```

You can then have a global object that you can set when your control's constructor after 
InitializeComponent();
DataContext=new GlobalObjectKnownAsViewModel(); // are the source of Binding

This approach would be a good first start and later you can look at maybe using PRISM/mvvm light  for additional behaviors and infrastructure they provide for mvvm work.